# Firestore security rules - allow if user status is verified

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want firebase security rules to allow if user verified==1 (0==waiting for approve & 2==blocked).

[image]

I try to using
`get(/UserAgentSecretInformation/$(request.auth.uid)).data.verified == 1`

But not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modify your code, use below line of code:

```
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/UserAgentSecretInformation/$(request.auth.uid)).data.verified == 1;
```